# Scheme/Racket: Syntax parser matching confused

Tags: parsing, syntax, scheme, lisp, racket

This code runs fine:

```
(require syntax/parse/define (only-in racket [#%app racket:#%app]))
(define-syntax-parser #%app
    [(_ Cond {~datum ?} Form1 ...) 
    #'(when Cond Form1 ...)]
    [(_ Cond {~datum ??} Form1 ... {~datum :} Form2 ...) 
    #'(if Cond (begin Form1 ...) (begin Form2 ...))]
    [(_ Xs ...) 
    #'(racket:#%app Xs ...)]
)

(#t ? (displayln 1))
(#t ?? (displayln 1) : (displayln 2))
```

However, I wish to change `??` to a single `?`. Racket shows error, why doesn't Racket match the second syntax?

```
:: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
```

Is Racket confused the `if` syntax with the right above `when` syntax? **How to fix it to use the same `?`** for both `when` and `if`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out how, the `when` is defined first before the `if` in `define-syntax-parser`, and its syntax include ellipsis `...` which matches everything following it, including the `:` in if-else.

Fixed it as below, put syntax for `if` first:

```
(require syntax/parse/define (only-in racket [#%app racket:#%app]))
(define-syntax-parser #%app
    [(_ Cond {~datum ?} Form1 ... {~datum :} Form2 ...) 
    #'(if Cond (begin Form1 ...) (begin Form2 ...))]
    [(_ Cond {~datum ?} Form1 ...) 
    #'(when Cond Form1 ...)]
    [(_ Xs ...) 
    #'(racket:#%app Xs ...)]
)

(#t ? (displayln 1))
(#t ? (displayln 1) : (displayln 2))
```